# How to export civievent participant list to a csv file?

Tags: civievent, export, csv

How can I add the ability to export to a csv file? Right now the only export option on the actions menu is to a Microsoft Excel file.

Comment: Do you happen to have installed an extension to export to excel? like one of these: https://civicrm.org/extensions?title=excel&body_value=&field_extension_cms_tid=All&field_extension_ready_value=All&sort_by=field_extension_current_usage_value&sort_order=DESC

Answer (score 1):

What version of Civi are you using?

Under Events > Reports > Participant List, Mine shows "Export CSV" as an Action Option

Under Search > Find Participants, it just says "Export List", But when I export it I get a CSV file.

But even if you get a .xls or other Excel file you can always save it as a .csv in Excel. If you do not have Excel, then run it through an online file converter. You can even open the Excel file in Google Sheets and then download it as a csv to convert it.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm new to civi so I'm still putting all of the pieces together. The .xlsx file that is created is corrupt and Excel can't read it. I was getting that file via Find Participants, but that only gives me a .xlsx file.  csv wasn't an option. I finally found the reports and was able to export as a csv.

Comment: Your version of Excel might be older and cannot open .xlsx files. But you still should be able to use a online converter or Google Sheets to get it converted into a csv. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Pls be specific about the route you used to get where you are seeing this, and the wording you see or attach a screenshot. I checked on demo and under Adv Search and under Find Participants i do not see where it specifies the download is an Excel document.